# how to use value from js in href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

how to get data-phone (from alloka.js, doesn't matter) value in href?

this doesn't work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://analytics.alloka.ru/v4/alloka.js" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var href = $('span').attr('data-phone');
        $('.t282__logo').attr( 'href', href); 
    })
</script> 
<a class="t282__logo"  href="tel:"><span class="phone-alloka"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [jQuery Data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) official documentation in order to  and change your script from

```
var href = $('span').attr('data-phone');
```

to

<s>`var href = $('span').data('phone');`</s>

**EDIT**

```
var href = $('.phone-alloka').data('phone'); // In this way you select the specific span
```

Another way may be:

```
var href = $('span[data-phone]').data('phone');
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. the attribute i'm trying to get is called "data-phone"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data()`. jQuery reads cached data first, and if it doesn't exist, reads `data-*` attributes.

```
var href = $('span').data('phone');
```

Additionally, you need to be sure that `data-phone` is set when your code executes. It is possible that it may not be present during the execution of your code.

Comment: it is loading on the page, because span class "phone-alloka" gets data from it as text.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

First you have to add **data-phone** to the span, then give it an id. 
Then access it as follows. Run and see the log results, you will see the href is being changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var href = $('#demo').data('phone');
  
  console.log("Before : "+ $('.t282__logo').attr( 'href'));
  
  $('.t282__logo').attr( 'href', href); 
  
  console.log("After : "+ $('.t282__logo').attr( 'href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://analytics.alloka.ru/v4/alloka.js" ></script>

<a class="t282__logo"  href="tel:"> Changing href
  <span id="demo" class="phone-alloka" data-phone="www.google.com"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: still nothing:

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://analytics.alloka.ru/v4/alloka.js" >
$(document).ready(function() {
var href = $('#demid').attr('data-phone');
 $('.t282__logo').attr( 'href', href); 

})
</script> 

   
<a class="t282__logo"  href="tel:"><span class="phone_alloka" id="demid" data-phone="value"> </span></a>

Comment: It's fixed now. Working